# How to enable Spring Cloud Contract Wiremock server logging?

Tags: java, logging, spring-test, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

As per official document [How to Debug](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/3.0.2-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-debug), I need to add following to the property file to enable logging

```
logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
logging.level.com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock=DEBUG
```

But, I don't see any logs visible on the console when request sent to wiremock server. I'm getting `500 Internal Server Error` only specific platform. So, to troubleshoot I'm trying to intercept activity when request reached to wiremock server.

In my pom file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also tried adding `logback-test.xml` file with following content. But, this is not logging anything as well.

```
<logger name="com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock" level="DEBUG"/> 
<logger name="wiremock.org" level="DEBUG"/> 
<logger name="WireMock" level="DEBUG"/> 
<logger name="/" level="DEBUG"/>
```

My test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(
    locations = "/application-integration-test.properties"
)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "100000")
public class MyApplicationTest {

  private WebTestClient client;

  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;


  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    client = WebTestClient.bindToServer().baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port).build();
  }

  /// Test code 

}
```

Anyone suggest what am missing ?

Comment: Did you try add `ConsoleNotifier` from official docs [WIREMOCK](http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/) see section Notification (logging)

Comment: could you share the example, which be fit for above code. This existing code and I don't know how to use `ConsoleNotifier` in this case. I can't change the entire flow for enabling the log. That will impact whole flow.

Comment: try to add in your `setUp` method   `WireMockConfiguration.options()
                .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true));`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using WireMock via Spring annotation `@AutoConfigureWireMock`, best way to see WireMock (verbose) logs in test console output should be to add this bean in your test class:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class WireMockTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    WireMockConfigurationCustomizer optionsCustomizer() {
        return config -> config.notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true));
    }
}
```

You may use `@Import` to add `WireMockTestConfiguration` to Spring context.